# How to make views visible and collapsed depending on whether the corresponding module is loaded or not?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a prism application already in production.

I need to create a new module in this application.The module can either exist on not exist in the application depending on the configuration file.

This module view should be dispalyed in a region already existing. The view should only be visible when the module is loaded.

Problem: the existing screen has a region showing 2 tab items from 2 different modules. Now the new view should be part of the first tab and it gives the user the option to select whether to view the previous info or the new info from this new module.
I am stuck and dont know how I am going to show these checkboxes when the new module is loaded and hide it when it is not. Where do I put this logic?

[image: Needed]

Current scenario:
[image: CurrentImage]

Very vague images to define what i meant?

Comment: How about a ContenControl, which has an empty ContentTemplate if the module is not loaded, and the correct ContentTemplate with your module settings if it is loaded. Can be easily achieved with some ViewModel logic and datatrigger.

Comment: I will look into this solution but still i dont know where will i put this contentcontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help :)

After a lot of RND i figure it out. 
I have created a two tabcontrol regions one for the main tab and the other for the child tab.
on the child tab i have return style to display tabitem only if item.count is more then 1 as suggested by mark.

and i have put this code in my existing module.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that will work, and isn't too much effort...

Inside your beautifully illustrated Tab1, add another tab control, and make this a Prism region. Fill this region with both the original view, and the view from your new module.

Then, restyle the inner tab control, if necessary, so the tab headers appear like radio buttons, and set up a datatrigger to hide the tab header strip if the number if tabs is less than or equal to 1.